# No such module 'AWSAppSync'

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying the AWS Amplify for iOS. 
I did what the [Amplify guidance](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api) told me to.

- install 'AWSCore' and 'AWSAppSync' by CocoaPods
- drag 'app.swift' file into my project
- open the '.xcworkspace' and build the project

An Error like  *'No such module 'AWSAppSync''* showed up in the 'API.swift' file.

[image: ERROR 1]

And another error is *'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<_>'* in the SQLite.swift.

[image: ERROR 2]

I've tried deleting the DerivedData files, clean and rebuild the project, but the error is still there.

WHY??

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/920, it seems to be a swift version problem.

> If not on Swift 5+, use old datatypeValue implementation #930

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it seems working in my case.